# Redmine Installation with activerecord-mysql-adapter

Tags: ruby, linux, installation, redmine, gemfile

I'm working on a CentOS 6.3 Linux server with the Ruby version: 1.8.7 and the Gem version: 1.8.25

I'm trying to run the command: `ruby script/rails server webrick -e production`

It spits out this error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:157:in `gem': Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (can't activate mysql (~> 2.8.1), already activated mysql-2.9.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:5
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:721
    from /var/www/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2
    from /var/www/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12
    from /var/www/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
    from /var/www/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /var/www/redmine/config/environment.rb:14
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:4
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:1
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.2"
gem "i18n", "~> 0.6.0"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.0.6"
gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]
gem "builder", "3.0.0"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem "rack", "1.4.0"
gem "rubytree", "0.5.2", :require => "tree"
gem "RedCloth", "~>4.2.3", :require => "redcloth" # for CodeRay
gem "mysql", "2.9.0"

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
  gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.3.1"
end

# Optional gem for OpenID authentication
group :openid do
  gem "ruby-openid", "~> 2.1.4", :require => "openid"
  gem "rack-openid"
end

# Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file, not supported with jruby
platforms :mri, :mingw do
  group :rmagick do
    # RMagick 2 supports ruby 1.9
    # RMagick 1 would be fine for ruby 1.8 but Bundler does not support
    # different requirements for the same gem on different platforms
    gem "rmagick", ">= 2.0.0"
  end
end

# Database gems
platforms :mri, :mingw do
  group :postgresql do
    gem "pg", ">= 0.11.0"
  end

  group :sqlite do
    gem "sqlite3"
  end
end

platforms :mri_18, :mingw_18 do
  group :mysql do
    gem "mysql", "2.9.0"
  end
end

platforms :mri_19, :mingw_19 do
  group :mysql do
    gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
  end
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem "jruby-openssl"

  group :mysql do
    gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter"
  end

  group :postgresql do
    gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter"
  end

  group :sqlite do
    gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter"
  end
end

group :development do
  gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2"
  gem "yard"
end

group :test do
  gem "shoulda", "~> 2.11"
  # Shoulda does not work nice on Ruby 1.9.3 and seems to need test-unit explicitely.
  gem "test-unit", :platforms => [:mri_19]
  gem "mocha", "0.12.3"
end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")
if File.exists?(local_gemfile)
  puts "Loading Gemfile.local ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`
  instance_eval File.read(local_gemfile)
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/Gemfile", __FILE__) do |file|
  puts "Loading #{file} ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`
  instance_eval File.read(file)
end
```

I've installed activerecord-mysql-adapter -- it had no errors...

I've tried to change the Gemfile to match the error it's spitting out, the (~> 2.8.1) version but that did not work either...

Any help would really be appreciated...

UPDATE!!

I uninstalled MySQL 2.9.0 and installed MySQL 2.8.1 and changed my Gemfile to reflect the proper version, but now I'm getting this error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query': Mysql::Error: Table 'redmine.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users` (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `log'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:324:in `execute_and_free'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:426:in `columns'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `call'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `[]'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:237:in `columns_hash'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:19:in `descends_from_active_record?'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:25:in `finder_needs_type_condition?'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:455:in `relation'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:37:in `scoped'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `order'
    from /var/www/redmine/app/models/group.rb:32
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /var/www/redmine/config/environment.rb:14
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:4
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /var/www/redmine/config.ru:1
```

EDIT: I figured it out... I needed to run the command: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate`

DOH!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle exec ruby script/rails server webrick -e production
```

Also, why are you using script/rails? This should work:

```
 bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```

HTH

Comment: I tried that and still got an error... seems to be the same thing.. I took that line directly from the installation instructions on the Redmine site

Comment: As for your update up there. Have you run rake db:migrate? Also are you sure you want to run it with the production environment? If you're sure then you probably need rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production.